# Loop property of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, local-storage

I store a shopping-cart in localStorage. If I click a new product I want to add it to the cart. If I click the same product again I want to add to the quantity to avoid double entries.

I want to loop through objects and check if the "id" property of the object matches the "Id" param sent to the function. If so i want to update the "qty" of that object, else create a new object and add to the "cart". Right now I'm looping to check if every property matches the "Id"-param.

This is what on object looks like:

```
{id:Id, qty: Qty, price: Price}
```

This is the function:

```
handleAdd =(Id, Qty, Price) =>{
        var newCart=[]
        var cart = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Cart'))

    if(cart !== null){
    for(var x in cart)
    {
        if(x.id === Id){
            x.qty = Number(x.qty) + Number(Qty) 

        }
        else{
            var item = {id:Id, qty: Qty, price: Price}
            newCart.push(item)
        }
    }
    }else{
         newCart= {id:Id, qty: Qty, price: Price}
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('Cart', JSON.stringify(newCart))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: just realised that my sample code didn't add the item if the cart existed in storage, but the item wasn't present in the cart

You don't need to build a new cart from the existing one, just use the one already in the storage. Something like this:

```
handleAdd = (Id, Qty, Price) => {
    let cart = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Cart'));
    // Track if item is already present
    let itemPresent = false;

    if(cart !== null){
        for(let i=0; i< cart.length; i++)
        {
            if (cart[i].id === Id) {
                cart[i].qty = Number(cart[i].qty) + Number(Qty);
                itemPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If item wasn't present, add it to cart
        if (itemPresent === false) {
            cart.push({id:Id, qty: Qty, price: Price});
        }
    } else {
         cart = [{id:Id, qty: Qty, price: Price}];
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('Cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}
```

In future questions include what the problem is with your current method's behaviour, any error messages you get, etc.